# Bypassing MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> In MySQL, comments can be inserted within **keywords** themselves,
>   which provides another means of *bypassing* some input validation
>   filters while preserving the syntax of the actual query. For example:

```
SEL/*foo*/ECT username,password FR/*foo*/OM users
```

But how is it possible to comment out things between preserved words? what's the advantage?
And why it's a kind of bypassing?

*It seems buggy!*

Comment: Your code will not work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee99b/8 .. (or I misunderstood someting)

Comment: The parser will certaily skip/strip out those comments. The advantages? I don’t know. But it’ll fool measures that look for certain keywords or patterns like `SELECT … FROM …`.

Comment: tnx all, the below answer clarifies these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That quote is from a book from 2007](http://books.google.com/books?id=YJKbVzeabJYC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=%22In%20MySQL,%20comments%20can%20even%20be%20inserted%20within%20keywords%20themselves%22&source=bl&ots=uLs_sZ32ny&sig=nkQslgFoZFRehvx17pX2AC0NT5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lOBMUbfZBsXbiwLL3oC4CA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22In%20MySQL,%20comments%20can%20even%20be%20inserted%20within%20keywords%20themselves%22&f=false)... it may have been true for earlier versions of MySql, but I can't find a MySQL version where that syntax doesn't return an error.

The original idea behind this syntax would be that if the application was trying to *blacklist* certain SQL keywords, then this attack would fool the application.

For example... if the application was trying to prevent an attacker from using Sql Injection to delete records from the database, a blacklist of terms to disallow would filter out `DELETE`... but fail to filter out `DEL/**/ETE`.

However, trying to create a blacklist of terms to disallow in your dynamic queries is a **terrible, ineffective** approach to preventing SQL injection... and there are much easier and effective means of preventing SQL injection attacks, such as parameterized queries, that would render the embedded comment syntax useless even if it were still valid.

[From OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection):

> As is almost always the case, blacklisting is riddled with loopholes
>   that make it ineffective at preventing SQL injection attacks. For
>   example, attackers can:
>
> - Target fields that are not quoted
> - Find ways to bypass the need for certain escaped meta-characters
> - Use stored procedures to hide the injected meta-characters

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [**Michael Fredrickson perfect answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15581100/944948)
[check out the mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html) and you see this way of commenting mentioned in all version of mysql.
In my version (5.5.24) if you write a query like this below:

```
sele/*ops*/ct name from tableName
```

You will get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sele/*ops*/ct name from
tableName' at line 1
```

But if you change it to this:

```
select na/*ops*/me from tableName
```

You will get this:

```
Unknown column 'na' in 'field list'
```

I think it comments the rest of field name. but if you write the query like this, it works without any problem:

```
select name/*ops*/ from tableName
```

Comment: Yes, actually I didn't know new versions of mysql omitted this ability! The way of commenting isn't sth to be changed in releasing new versions so I didn't doubt!